# MS Access Query Subselect or Union with Left Join

Tags: ms-access

I am an Access noob and am working with a database that tracks employee injuries and missed time.  I have a query that pulls data from two tables:  one with employee injuries and the other with missed time.  Most injuries do not have any associated missed time, and there are two types of missed time.  Currently, the query returns a separate row for each type of missed time.  I would like to modify this query so that there will be only one row for each employee with two separate columns for the different types of missed time.  My column headings would go from this:

Date of Incident, Employee’s name, Leave_Type, Days

To this:

Date of Incident, Employee’s name, Days Off, Days on Light Duty

The query is below.  The two types of leave are "Off" and "TTA".  Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
SELECT 
Injuries.[Date of Incident], 
Injuries.[Employee's name], 
Leave.Leave_Type, 
Sum(IIf(Leave.Last Is Null,DateDiff("d",Leave.First,Date())+1, DateDiff("d",Leave.First,Leave.Last)+1)) AS Days
FROM 
Injuries LEFT JOIN Leave ON Injuries.ID = Leave.ID
WHERE 
Injuries.[OSHA Recordable?]<0 
and Injuries.[Date of Incident] between [Forms]![OSHA Recordable Claims Form]![From] and [Forms]![OSHA Recordable Claims Form]![To]
GROUP BY 
Injuries.[Date of Incident], 
Injuries.[Employee's name], 
Leave.Leave_Type
ORDER BY 
Injuries.[Date of Incident];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options come to mind:

You can do a cross-tab query with Leave-Type as the column heading

Or you can put a formula in each of two columns

```
OFF_leave:Iif (leave_type="Off",<calc the amount here>,0)

TTA_Leave:Iif (leave_type="TTA",<calc the amount here>,0)
```

Each column will sum the appropriate leave types.

Comment: The cross-tab query worked after I remembered to declare the Between parameters.  Thanks!